# Do While Loop Problems

Tags: java, do-while

So I'm prompting the user to input a number between 1-12. If they don't meet the requirement, the loop runs it again. My loop keeps having an error.

**CODE**

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HW7 {

    public static int inputMonth(Scanner in) {
        int input = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        boolean flag = true;

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter a month between 1-12:");

            if (in.hasNextInt()) {
                input = in.nextInt();
                in.nextLine();
                if (input >= 1 && input <= 12) {
                    flag = false;
                }
            }

        } while (flag);

        return input;
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

Enter a month between 1-12:
Enter a month between 1-12:
Enter a month between 1-12:
Enter a month between 1-12:
Enter a month between 1-12:
Enter a month between 1-12:
Enter a month between 1-12:
Enter a month between 1-12:
Enter a month between 1-12:
Enter a month between 1-12:
Enter a month between 1-12:
Enter a month between 1-12;
...
...
...

Its keeps going.

Comment: if the input does not have an `int`, the input is not being read and loop will try again, but the wrong values are still there waiting to be read. Read a line (e.g. `in.nextLine()`) in an `else` block (for `if hasNextInt`)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the condition, `if(in.hasNextInt())`. Also, `flag` should be reset for every wrong/invalid input e.g. `flag = false` should be placed inside the loop. I also recommend you put exception handling code to handle the invalid input.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Test
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(inputMonth(in));
    }

    public static int inputMonth(Scanner in) {
        int input = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        boolean flag = false;
        do {
            flag = false;
            System.out.print("Enter a month between 1-12: ");
            try {
                input = in.nextInt();
                if (input < 1 || input > 12) {
                    System.out.println("The month must be between 1-12. Please try again.");
                    in.next();
                    flag = true;
                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("This is an invalid input. Please try again.");
                in.next();
                flag = true;
            }
        } while (flag);

        return input;
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a month between 1-12: 2
2
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter a month between 1-12: w
This is an invalid input. Please try again.
Enter a month between 1-12: 15
The month must be between 1-12. Please try again.
0
Enter a month between 1-12: 3
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your main method:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
inputMonth(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        inputMonth(in);
    }
    public static int inputMonth(Scanner in) {
        int input= Integer.MIN_VALUE; 
        boolean flag=true;
        do{
            System.out.println("Enter a month between 1-12:");
            if(in.hasNextInt()){
                input=in.nextInt();
                in.nextLine();
                if(input>=1 && input<=12) {
                    flag=false;
                    
                }
            }   
        } while(flag);

        return input;
    }
}
```

In order to use a Scanner object you have to initalize it, you will also need to import the library from java that's why `import java.util.Scanner;` is done

Comment: if user enters something that is not an `int` this will loop for ever (as in question) - `hasNextInt` returns `false` and since i o input is read, it will continue returning `false` for each iteration